# Laravel dependency injection "not instantiable"

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel

I have spent a day trying debugging and trying to understand what is going wrong but...

So here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace RememberCalories\Rest;

interface MyJsonResponseInterface
{
    public function getResponse();
}
```

And here is the class which I want to inject:

```
<?php

namespace RememberCalories\Rest;

class MyJsonResponse implements MyJsonResponseInterface
{
    protected $success;
    protected $responseCode;
    protected $responseMsg;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data, $responseCode=0, $responseMsg='')
    {
        $this->data         = $data;
        $this->responseCode = $responseCode;
        $this->responseMsg  = $responseMsg;

        if ( $this->responseCode === 0 ) {
            $this->success = true;
        }
    }
...
```

Binding:

```
\App::bind('MyJsonResponseInterface', function($app, $parameters) {
    $obj = new \RememberCalories\Rest\MyJsonResponse(null);
//    var_dump($obj);
//    die();

    return $obj;
});
```

And at last the controller:

```
<?php

use \RememberCalories\MainMenu\MainMenu;
use \RememberCalories\Repository\TargetEloquentRepository as TargetRepository;
use \RememberCalories\Rest\MyJsonResponseInterface;
//use \RememberCalories\Rest\MyJsonResponse;

class BaseController extends Controller 
{
    protected $viewVars;
    protected $mainMenu;

    //Dependency injection classes
    protected $target;
    protected $myJsonResponse;


    public function __construct(TargetRepository $target, MyJsonResponseInterface $myJsonResponse )
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('accessFilter');

        $this->target       = $target;
        //$this->myJsonResponse = $myJsonResponse;

        $this->mainMenu = (new MainMenu())->build();

        $this->prepareViewVariables();
    }
```

So the problem is with the second parameter of BaseController: MyJsonResponseInterface. The first is injected without problems but this one I get an error:

> Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
>
> Target [RememberCalories\Rest\MyJsonResponseInterface] is not
>   instantiable.

It seems that the Closure in \App::bind('MyJsonResponseInterface' ...) is not called.
I have moved it to service provider with the same result.

But at the same if to call manually `\App::make('MyJsonResponseInterface')`  everything is created ideally.

Please advise what way to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `App::bind` the full namespace - so in your example, `App::bind('RememberCalories\Rest\MyJsonResponseInterface')`.